# How to force a broken image to show on remote server?

Tags: html, image, animated-gif

When tested on my local machine, the .gif image was showing and looping just fine. But as soon as I upload it on the remote server using FileZila, the .gif link is broken in all three major browsers (Chrome, Explorer and Mozilla).

I`m only facing the issue with the .gif because all other image extensions (png and jpg) display fine.

Like I said, it works on my localhost but not on the remote. The image is there in the specified directory. I'd like to force the image to show up.

```
 <img src="../images/insta.gif" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
```

Comment: Yes, because most likely the path is incorrect. The image needs to be in a folder one step up from the file containing the given markup, as you used `../`

Comment: It may be that the web server is not configured to handle the gif extension... Do you know how the files are being hosted?

Comment: @ne1410s Since `gif` is the oldest file format used for html pages, that is _very_ unlikely

Comment: @LGSon Haha. True 

Comment: AdBlock Plus/Ublock Origin maybe?

Comment: Maybe your pathing on the localhost is different to that on the remote server. Also you can press CTRL+SHIFT+I and select Network>Images tab and diagnose the error from there. Its elementary really.

Comment: Do you have png and jpg images in the same location as gif or they are at different location?

Comment: @ne1410s: I think you are right because everytime I refresh the file manager through FileZila and open htdocs, the insta.gif file always appears missing. I have to put it back manually and even when it's in the directory it doesnt display. I'm using byethost.That is an issue if the gif cant play because it 's the company's brand commercial.

Comment: @VivekAthalye: Yes all the images are in the same folder.

Comment: @ne1410s: I'm with byethost but the nameserveers actually point to cloudflare.So maybe cloudflare doesnt allow gif extension and treat them like malwares?

Comment: @ne1410s: I was thinking about adding a specific rule to the .htaccess to prevent host from constantly removing .gif file. Is that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much Apache, but this sort of thing happened to me in IIS recently. Hope you manage to resolve it